# Show that this second type Fredholm equation doesn't admit a solution using fredholm theorems

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory, integral-equations

Given the following fredholm integral equation $g(s) =f(s)+\lambda\int_{0}^{2 \pi}sin(t+s) g(t) dt$ defined from $C[0,2\pi]$ over itself.  Show that if $f(s) =s$ then the equation doesn't have solution ¿what about $f(s) =1$?.

Hi, I need to prove this problem using fredholm theorems (the ones that relate the primal no homogeneous equation with the dual homogeneous equation and viceversa) and I don't understand those theorems yet.

Comment: If $\lambda=0$, $g=f$ is the solution.

Comment: I suppose that for $\lambda\neq0$ then, otherwise the exercise would be pointless .